# Git permission denied on boot: conq: repository access denied

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I have a script (sb_start_main) that calls another script (check_for_updates) that pulls a git repo. When I run either script (sb_start_main or check_for updates) directly it is successful. I added an echo statement with the timestamp and the current user (which is sookbox as expected).

```
bash /home/sookbox/update_testing/check_for_updates
sookbox Current time stamp: Tue Jun 11 11:51:47 EDT 2013
.....checking for updates
.....fetching origin master
.....current version of master  :  v1.6
```

I added the script sb_start_main to rc.local so that it is run on startup. When I do this the script no longer works, even though it is running as the correct user, sookbox:

```
sookbox Current time stamp: Tue Jun 11 11:49:28 EDT 2013
.....checking for updates
.....fetching origin master
conq: repository access denied.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is that this fails on boot because I just tried scheduling this as a cronjob to run `@reboot` and it failed in the exact same way. I've tried running the script through rc.local and adding a sleep before it in case the issue was that internet access had not started up yet, but that didn't work.

Thoughts?

Comment: Is your private key protected by a passphrase?

Comment: I'm not sure, how would I check that? I don't usually have to type a password to pull from git (also as evidenced by the script working without a password when I run it directly).

Comment: From a shell, is `SSH_AGENT` set in your environment?

Comment: Can you provide more details on how `check_for_updates` is trying to connect?

Comment: The line it breaks at reads: git fetch --quiet origin master:remotes/origin/master